# Automatically update a table from another one in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want know if it's possible to automatically update a table from another one in BigQuery.

Here's how the situation presents itself:

- I'm using a table from another project → `TableA`
- From `TableA`, I create a table in my project by filtering the data that I need → `TableB`
- I then create different views from `TableB` with specific queries → `ViewA`, `ViewB`, ...

[Explanation Diagramme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7fOp.png)

These views are then used with Google Sheets to monitor the project. 
I'm wondering if it's possible for TableB to be updated automatically with the new data from TableA when a query is used on `TableB` (For example, when you update a view on google sheet from connected sheets).
I'm using BigQuery and the module bq to create the tables.

Comment: There are [materialized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-manage) for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible, The BigQuery service allows you to use the Google BigQuery API in Apps Script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery and you can trigger from google sheets https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers.

My view is this may be an expensive way to query your data  if a user wants to flick back and fourth  between views because you are running the data each time a query is used, it might be worth looking into caching the data following a either in  BigQuery or Sheets.